# How to convert an image string into a stream in Ruby

Tags: ruby, curl, rmagick, curb

I use Ruby Gem curb to fetch image by the method of body_str of Curl::Easy instance, then want to use RMagick to process the image, however Magick::Image.read needs a file name to read, but what i get is the content string of the image. Yes, i know i can firstly convert the image content string into a file, then pass the file name to Magick::Image.read method. But that will add one more IO operation.

So i want to know whether it's possible to convert an image content string into stream directly, so that i can use RMagick to read it directly.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check other class methods of `Image` class, particularly [`from_blob`](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image1.html#from_blob). Sounds like what you need.

Comment: :-), yes, thank you very much, just now i am walk through one by one and find it's just suitable for what i want to do. Thank you thank you very very much for your answer in time.